# Creating a new column by resetting cummin() of another column and a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [98, 97, 100, 135, 103, 100, 105, 109, 130],
        'b': [100, 103, 101, 105, 110, 120, 101, 150, 160]
    }
)
```

And this is the desired output. I want to create column `c`:

```
     a    b    c
0   98  100  100
1   97  103  100
2  100  101  100
3  135  105  100
4  103  110  110
5  100  120  110
6  105  101  101
7  109  150  150
8  130  160  150
```

It is not so easy for me to describe the issue in pure English, since it is a little bit complicated.`c` is `df.b.cummmin()` but under certain conditions it changes. I describe it row by row:

The process starts with:

```
df['c'] = df.b.cummin()
```

The condition that changes `c` is :

```
cond = df.a.shift(1) > df.c.shift(1)
```

Now the rows that matter are the ones that `cond == True`. For these rows `df.c = df.b` And the `cummin()` of `b` RESETS.

For example, the first instance of `cond` is row `4`. So `c` changes to 110 (in other words, whatever `b` is). And for row `5` it is the `cummin()` of `b` from row `4`. The logic is the same to the end.

This is one of my attempts. But it does not work where the `cond` kicks in:

```
df['c'] = df.b.cummin()
df.loc[df.a.shift(1) > df.c.shift(1), 'c'] = df.b
```

---

PS:

The accepted answer works for this example. But for my real data which is way bigger than this, it didn't work as expected. I still haven't found the problem with it.

However I really like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77749796/10200497) answer and it works for me. It is simple and very effective. I didn't change the accepted answer because it has a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try :

```
m1 = df["b"].le(df["a"].shift())

cm = df["b"].groupby(m1.cumsum()).cummin()

m2 = (df["b"].le(cm) | df["a"].shift().le(cm.shift()))

df["c"] = cm.where(m2, df["b"].mask(m2).cummin())
```

Output (*including intermediates*) :

```
     a    b    c    a_s     m1   cm     m2    c
0   98  100  100    NaN  False  100   True  100
1   97  103  100  98.00  False  100   True  100
2  100  101  100  97.00  False  100   True  100
3  135  105  100 100.00  False  100   True  100
4  103  110  110 135.00   True  110   True  110
5  100  120  110 103.00  False  110   True  110
6  105  101  101 100.00  False  101   True  101
7  109  150  150 105.00  False  101  False  150
8  130  160  150 109.00  False  101  False  150

[9 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it's not a generic approach, right? It looks like you'd need to add a loop in order to generalize it.

Comment: @wjandrea I have worked with it for other examples. And yeah, it seems that something is wrong with it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @x_Amir_x I'm not sure how to improve this solution, but I did update my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

i can't find a way to do vectorized operations.

Try while:

```
df['c'] = None
while df['c'].isna().sum() > 0: 
    df2 = df[df['c'].isna()]
    s = df2['a'].gt(df2['b'].cummin()).shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum()
    idx = df2[s.eq(0)].index
    df.loc[idx, 'c'] = df.loc[idx, 'b'].cummin()
```

df

```
    a   b   c
0   98  100 100
1   97  103 100
2   100 101 100
3   135 105 100
4   103 110 110
5   100 120 110
6   105 101 101
7   109 150 150
8   130 160 150
```

---

**intermediate**

first run of while

```
       df
    a   b   c           s
0   98  100 100         0
1   97  103 100         0
2   100 101 100         0
3   135 105 100         0
4   103 110 None        1
5   100 120 None        2
6   105 101 None        2
7   109 150 None        3
8   130 160 None        4
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to vectorize this, but at least it's easy in plain Python and it's *O(n)*.

```
# Cumulative minimum, conditionally
k = None  # For first loop
c = []
for b, a_prev in zip(df['b'], df['a'].shift()):
    if k is None or b < k or a_prev > k:
        k = b
    c.append(k)

df.assign(c=c)
```

```
     a    b    c
0   98  100  100
1   97  103  100
2  100  101  100
3  135  105  100
4  103  110  110
5  100  120  110
6  105  101  101
7  109  150  150
8  130  160  150
```

If you need performance, [you might be able to use Cython or Numba](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html).

Comment: You answer is correct. I actually tested in on my original data which is way bigger than this. Your answer and the other answer by Panda Kim give the same result. But it is way slower than Timeless. I really like Timeless approach but yesterday I tested it and it did not work. I really hope that they improve that answer. Let`s wait :)

Comment: @x_Amir_x Did you see the note at the bottom? Did you try Cython or Numba?

Comment: not yet. You know this issue appears when I was converting from PineScript to Python. PineScript logic is way different than Pandas. I was like, we don't do that here :) Thanks. Already a thumbs up